# Bottle won't let me access drop down menu items in forms

Tags: python, web-applications, bottle

I have a small web app set up with Bottle. It can read a normal text box with `request.forms.get` from a POST form, but not a `<select>` field with a drop down menu.

The HTML looks fine don't have it here but can post along with app code if needed.

EDIT:

```
@bottle.post('/combat')
def combat():
    thing = bottle.request.forms.get('name')
    print(bottle.request.forms.get('river'))

    print(type(thing),dir(thing),thing)
    return("THANKS FOR FIGHTING")

#print("starting server")
bottle.run(host='localhost',port=8080)
```

And the template:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="/combat" method="post">

Choose your attacker:

<select name="attacker">
    % for unit in unitlist:
        <option value="{{unit}}">{{unit}}</option>
    % end    
</select>
<p>

Choose your defender:

<select name="defender">
    % for unit in unitlist:
        <option value="{{unit}}">{{unit}}</option>
    % end    
</select>
<p>

Location:
<select name="location">
    <option value="open">Out in the Open</option><br>
    <option value="city">In a City</option><br>
    <option value="fort">In a Fort</option>
</select>
    <p>

<input type="checkbox" name="river" value="True">On a river<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fortified" value="True">Fortified<br>
<p>


<input name="name" type="text" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can post what it renders to, if that helps?

Comment: Please include the code you've written so far. The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have done - thanks for the formatting help too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems it was a false alarm - it's working now, and I haven't changed very much! Not sure what the problem is, other than having now turned Debug mode on and fiddled with the code that displayed `bottle.forms.get`!

Hope I haven't wasted people's time...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the view that is processing the posted data accepts a POST request and the select field should contain a proper **name**:

```
from bottle import get, post, request # or route

@get('/form') # or @route('/form')
def form():
    return '''
        <form action="/example" method="post">
            Select: <select name="example">
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
            <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
        </form>
    '''  

@post('/example') # or @route('/example', method='POST')
def example():
    select_field_data = request.forms.get('example')
    ...
```

Comment: I think I've done this - have updated the question with code. However, I notice that you've used `'select'` in `request.forms.get` rather than `'example'` - should I be doing this?